# lexical_cast with negative number behaves differently on different machines

Tags: c++, boost, lexical-cast

I have identical versions of boost on two different devices, yet the behavior is different for

```
lexical_cast<uint>("-1")
```

The documentation states that it should give me INT_MAX (2's complement rollover) but on one machine I get an exception throw while on the other one I get INT_MAX.

Comment: `INT_MAX`? Where does the documentation say that?

Comment: @Ant, [the FAQ](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast/frequently_asked_questions.html) talks about what happens when casting the *string* `"-1"` to `uint` (which ultimately relies on C's rules for `scanf`), but I see nothing in the documentation about casting `-1`. In fact, I see nothing about casting from any non-string type to another non-string type, except where it suggests that `numeric_cast` "may offer more reasonable behavior." So, Wonton, please provide a citation, and maybe tell why you're not using `numeric_cast`.

Comment: Forgot quotes. it's for string conversion. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently if you look at boost's code for `lexical_cast` the input is loaded and operated upon using code like this `interpreter << arg; interpreter >> result` and in the `>>` operator

```
this->setg(start, start, finish);             
std::basic_istream<CharT> stream(static_cast<Base*>(this));
stream.unsetf(std::ios::skipws);
```

It uses `std::basic_istream` so different versions of libstdc++ will cause `lexical_cast` to behave differently on different machines.

Comment: .·. documentation bug, at the very least.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you. How do different versions of `basic_istream` differ in a way that influences the code shown here?

Comment: I'm not sure that code is relevant anymore. The only place I was able to find code like that (in Boost 1.59) was in `lexical_cast_old.hpp` and it had the comment: `// call-by-value fallback version (deprecated)`

Comment: I got this code from boost 1_38 so it probably isn't as useful anymore, but I spent hours and hours on this so if even one person benefited I'd be a happy camper.